# Windows 10 unable to boot, stuck on autorepair: Critical boot file sxssrv is missing

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 machine is stuck in the autorepair loop. Already tried multiple fixes regarding `bootrec` like [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508) but it didn't work. After resetting it's still stuck on autorepair.

I opened `D:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt` and found a line that goes `Boot critical file D:\Windows\system32\sxssrv is missing`. I'm not sure is related but I am unable to find any information on this missing file.

How do I fix this?

**Context**

This error appeared after I inserted a `Ubuntu Live USB` into a USB 3.0 on my desktop. I clicked on the "Install" app but once it got to the partition screen, I cancelled everything and turned it off.  Went back to Windows but it didn't boot.

Also, yesterday Windows Update installed a big updates (Creators Update?) and this morning (before the ubuntu usb thing) I was able to turn it on with no problem (here is where I created the Ubuntu Live USB, and a Windows Media Recovery USB).

**UPDATE:**

I wasn't able to fix this, so I reinstalled Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP was unable to solve it and has resorted to a Windows reinstallation, making it unlikely that possible solutions can be confirmed.

Comment: I'll delete it as soon as I get home, give me half an hour

Comment: seems like i can't delete it

Comment: No, you can only delete a question that has no answers. That's OK though. It will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen alot of similar issues recently that we remedied through the use of a windows 10 install usb.

The basic process was to boot into the usb, select the language and formats, then select repair in the bottom left corner.

Once in the repair section, use the advanced options and there is two options to go through.

the first is, if your lucky, the option to use a different operating system (i know it sounds weird) and select the windows 10 option where available. The reason this works is when performing the upgrade/update windows makes a backup of the os that you can roll back to. This isn't 100% unfortunately as sometimes the backup is cleared immediately after first clean boot.

Your second option if the above fails or is unavailable is to perform the start up repairs available in the usb's repair options. This should restore missing portions of the windows system file.

And if all else fails look into the system restore function and using SFC in command prompt

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried selecting "different operating system" (windows 10 pro shows twice, none work. Startup repairs don't work. It says I don't have system restore (even though I actually do).

Comment: sorry it didn't help.